# How can install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386

Tags: apt, software-installation

Today I installed the Ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64 bit and I want to install the libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 packet. I execute the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
```

and I get the following results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6) or
                                 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**UPDATE**

I execute the command:

```
dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core
```

and I get:

```
ii  xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily                            2:1.17.2-1ubuntu9.1~trusty1                         amd64        Xorg X server - core server
```

**SECOND UPDATE**

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-wily:i386
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-wily:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 (= 11.0.2-1ubuntu4~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-wily:i386
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 : Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core` terminal command.

Comment: Include `libudev1:i386` and see what is needed next.

Comment: always required new dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You have `wily` graphical stack. The correct command should be

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-wily:i386 libudev1:i386
```

Comment: I have posted a second update in my question with the results from your command .

Comment: I updated the command.

Comment: I update the post with your updated command